# show multiple modal pop up in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using angularjs. What I want to do is to check student id in database by Angularjs, when the user  clicks a button.
If student id exists in database, #modal1 will be shown, otherwise #modal2 will be prompted. Is it possible to do this with angularjs? If possible how..

**Html**

```
<tr ng-repeat="g in students">
  <td>{{g.studentId}}</td>
  <td>{{g.studentName}}</td>
  <td>
    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="btnActions">
        <button type="button" ng-click="act(g)" title="act" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteModal"></button>    
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>

#Modal that will be displayed 
<!-- modal1 -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                confirm delete?
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="delete()">Yes</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" > No</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- modal2 -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal2" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                Data already existed
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.act = function (g) {
    g.studentId;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In controller write code

```
$scope.act = function(g){
    /*
       write code for check student is in database
    */
   if(student_available == true){
       $("#modal1").modal('show');
   }
   else{
       $("#modal2").modal('show');
   }
}
```